# Validation flashdata error is not displaying in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, flash-message

Here is my login method inside the controller, Here I am setting a flash message for the validation errors -

```
public function login(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $data = array(
          'errors' => validation_errors()
        );
        $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
        redirect('home');
    }
}
```

Here id the code to display those errors -

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors')): ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errors');?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know what is wrong, Error message is not displaying.

Comment: try like this $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors()); as a single item not as an array.

Comment: Check docs again. You have to load view, not to redirect in case form fails. Make redirection in else block after setting session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope work this process

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('name','Your message');
    redirect('home');
}
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('name')): ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('name');?>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its placed in controller**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {       
$errors = validation_errors();
           $this->session->set_flashdata('form_error', $errors);
           $this->load->view('Your View page');
}
```

**Its placed in your view page**

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('form_error')): ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('form_error');?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this it will help to you..!